# Ionic Native Geolocation sample not understanding the description demo code

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am using Ionic Native Geolocation plugin from [HERE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation) and to start with the example provided so I've done this:

```
getLocation() {

  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    // resp.coords.latitude
    // resp.coords.longitude
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
  });

  let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
  watch.subscribe((data) => {
    // data.coords.latitude
    // data.coords.longitude
  });
}
```

I don't understand the code ... does it seem to be doing the same thing twice?

It's got the ***getCurrentPosition*** and the ***watchPosition*** sections and both get the saqme data?

Why? I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In summery: **this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()** is used to retrieve the device's current location once, while **this.geolocation.watchPosition()** Registers a handler function that will be called automatically each time the position of the device changes, returning the updated location.

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Code Examples:

```
//define the userPositionWatch
userPositionWatch: any;
//Subscriber to the userPositionWatch
this.userPositionWatch = this.geolocation.watchPosition()
    .subscribe(
        (position: any) => {
            // This method will be triggered each time the position of the device changes
            console.debug("geolocation.watchPosition => the callback function have been triggered");
            let data: any = position;
            if (data.coords !== undefined) {
                this.doSomethingWithThePos(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);
            } else {
                console.error("geolocation.watchPosition() => the callback function have been triggered and the position is undefined", data);
            }
        }
        , (error: any) => {
            console.error("geolocation.watchPosition() => the callback function have been triggered and the there is an error:", error);
        });
//To remove the subscription 
this.userPositionWatch.unsubscribe();
//Another way to remove the subscription
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.userPositionWatch);


this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
    .then((position: any) => {
        let data: any = position;
        if (data.coords !== undefined) {
            this.doSomethingWithThePos(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);
        } else {
            console.error("geolocation.getCurrentPosition() => the position is undefined", data);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("geolocation.getCurrentPosition() => the position has error:", error);
    })
```

I hope it was clear...